# JMSSerializerBundle, SoftDeleteable, and Many-to-Many's in Doctrine / Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the Gedmo Doctrine Extensions and the SoftDeleteable extension in a system that has a lot of cross referenced data. I'm coming across scenarios like the following:

1. **Product A** is assigned **Supplier B**
2. **Supplier B** is [soft] deleted
3. **Product A** now throws an "entity does not exist" when Serialized because the "supplier" foreign key still has the ID for **Supplier B** even though the entity is soft deleted and can't be fetched.

It should be noted that I don't want the delete to cascade, meaning that I don't want to delete **Product A** just because **Supplier B** has been deleted. I just need the Supplier foreign key to be set to NULL (or to be interpreted as NULL by JMS) when the Supplier record is deleted.

This is such a common scenario, I can't image other people aren't experiencing this, but I'm failing to find any answers. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
-Nate

Comment: You need to set `null` the "supplier" foreign key at Product table manually. It depends how you builded the Product model to cascate or not the relationship.

Comment: So would that be through an event listener that fires before a Supplier entity is deleted that would manually perform the lookups and reset the keys to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

There is how I did for the same scenario:

Extended Doctrine Proxy Subscriber where EntityNotFoundException is thrown. To override the service just add parameter:

```
jms_serializer.doctrine_proxy_subscriber.class: YourCustom\JMSDoctrineProxySubscriber
```

On your custom DoctrineProxySubscriber

```
<?php

namespace YourCustom;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\Subscriber\DoctrineProxySubscriber;

class JMSDoctrineProxySubscriber extends DoctrineProxySubscriber
{
    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        try {
            parent::onPreSerialize($event);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException $e) {
            // The exception is thrown when soft-deleted objects are tried to be loaded.
            // Soft-deleted Doctrine proxy objects should be treated as null. Overriding event type which is eventually
            // a class name to stdClass would make it skip and result in as null.
            $event->setType('stdClass');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product = $em->find('models\ProductA', 1);
$supplier = $product->getSupplier();
$product->setSupplier(null);

$em->remove($supplier);
$em->flush();
```